# long long division in c

Tags: c

am trying to pass along a "long long" number, the problem is when I try to divise this number by 10 , the answer is incorrect ..

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n = 0 ;
    long long s = 4111111111111111;

    n = s % 10 ;
    printf("n after modulos %i\n",n );

    s = s / 10 ;
    printf("this is s after division %llo \n",s  );


    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
n after modulos 1
this is s after division 13536350357330707
```

Comment: What is your platform's largest supported `long long` value?

Comment: %llo -> %lld ; long long s = 4111111111111111L;

Comment: try doing `s = s / (long long)10`.

Comment: [This `printf` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be handy, especially the table with the different format specifiers.

Comment: o means octal. printf is printing the CORRECT answer, but in octal. Use d for a decimal answer. %lld

Comment: @kkk  I don't think suffix is required .

Comment: This is wrong **n = s % 10 ;** what is **n** and what is **s** ?

Comment: By the way using **%i** instead of **%d** its ok in here but will not be the same with scanf.

Comment: @kkk `long long s = 4111111111111111LL;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("this is s after division %llo \n",s  );
                                   ^ (this prints (correct)value in octal representation)
```

Use specifier `%lld` (to get value  in decimal ) .

Answer (score 1):

> man 3 printf

```
   o, u, x, X
          The  unsigned int argument is converted to unsigned octal (o), unsigned decimal (u), or unsigned hexadecimal (x and X) notation.  The letters abcdef are used for x conversions; the letters ABCDEF are
          used for X conversions.  The precision, if any, gives the minimum number of digits that must appear; if the converted value requires fewer digits, it is padded on the left with  zeros.   The  default
          precision is 1.  When 0 is printed with an explicit precision 0, the output is empty.
```

and some more on manual

> man 3p printf

```
   ll (ell-ell)

          Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a long long or unsigned long long argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a pointer  to  a  long
          long argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

To print a `long long`, you should use `%lld` not `%llo`

The `%llo` format is used for representing a `long long` value in `octal`.

Comment: yeah , it was the problem , when changed everything worked like a charm :)